# Showing that every topological space $X$ is homeomorphic to a closed subspace of its cone $C(X)$

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that every topological space $X$ is homeomorphic to a closed subspace of its cone $C(X)=(X\times [0,1])/(X\times \{1\})$.

My idea was to define the homeomorphism as $f=p \circ i$, where $p:X \times [0,1] \rightarrow C(X)$ is the canonical projection (which I know is surjective and continuous) and $i: X \times \{0\} \rightarrow X \times [0,1]$ is the inclusion (which I know is injective). Then, the result would follow if I could show that $f$ is a closed map (because I know $X\times \{0\}$ is closed in $X \times [0,1]$, then its image would be closed in $C(X)$.

I’m not sure how to do that though. Is the idea okay so far?

Comment: But $X \times \{0\}$ is closed in the cone already, so you're done.

Comment: More accurate: $p(X\times \{0\}) \subseteq C(X)$ is closed since $p^{-1}(p(X\times \{0\})) = X\times \{0\}\subseteq X \times [0,1]$ is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the quotient map $q:X\times [0,1]\to C(X)$ associated with the identification of the top $X \times \{1\}$ to a point and that induces the topology on $C(X)$ (it's not a canonical "projection").

And indeed an embedding $i: X \to X_0:=X \times \{0\}$ defined by $x \to (x,0)$ which is clearly an embedding (continuity is obvious, and so is the the continuity of the inverse etc.). And $X_0$ is closed in $X \times [0,1]$ (as $\{0\}$ is closed in $[0,1]$) and in the quotient topology $q\restriction_{X_0}$ is a bijection (we identify nothing, so 1-1 is trivial) with $q[X_0]$, which is closed in $C(X)$ as $q^{-1}[q[X_0]] = X_0$ is closed in $X \times [0,1]$. The composition of these two embeddings $i$ and $q \restriction_{X_0}$ is again an embedding and it is as required.

As both those maps are easily seen to be closed maps, so is their composition.